# "save" and "restore" R packages locally?

Tags: r

When I work on a project in R, there are many packages that may be updated or changed overtime. When I finish a project, I wish to save all of the packages at that time point. This way I can reproduce the result on my previous project if I can "restore" all of the packages in R used to produce the previous result. Is there a way to do this "save" and "restore" all of the R packages locally (without updating them to the most recent version)? Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat

Answer (score 0):

One option: you can do an install into a specific directory, then in your R code load the library from that location.  For example, to snapshot the forecast library you can use:

```
install.packages('forecast', lib='~/R/library_1')
```

followed by

```
library('forecast', lib='~/R/library_1')
```

of course, you code would need access to the library directory if you were to share it